# What is causing/how can I fix build error with 'sudo apt install python3-coral-enviro'? Is this a bug or is there a fix?

Tags: python, google-coral, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W with the latest image and with updates. The enviro board sits properly atop the Pi Zero.

I follow the instructions at [Get started with the Environmental Sensor Board](https://coral.ai/docs/enviro-board/get-started/#3-try-the-demo).

When executing on the command line:

```
sudo apt install python3-coral-enviro
```

I receive the following error:

```
> > Done. Loading new coral-enviro-drivers-1.5 DKMS files... It is likely that 5.10.11+ belongs to a chroot's host Building for 5.10.11+,
> 5.10.11-v7+, 5.10.11-v7l+ and 5.10.11-v8+ Building initial module for 5.10.11+ Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.11+ (armv6l) Consult /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/make.log
> for more information. dpkg: error processing package
> coral-enviro-drivers-dkms (--configure):  installed
> coral-enviro-drivers-dkms package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 10 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of python3-coral-enviro:  python3-coral-enviro depends
> on coral-enviro-drivers-dkms; however:   Package
> coral-enviro-drivers-dkms is not configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package python3-coral-enviro (--configure): 
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
> while processing:  coral-enviro-drivers-dkms  python3-coral-enviro E:
> Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/make.log shows:

```
> DKMS make.log for coral-enviro-drivers-1.5 for kernel 5.10.11+
> (armv6l) Sat 06 Feb 2021 07:51:13 PM CST make: Entering directory
> '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.11+'   CC [M] 
> /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/humidity/hdc20x0.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/light/opt3001.o   CC
> [M]  /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/adc/ti-ads1015.o
> /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/adc/ti-ads1015.c:797:16:
> error: ‘iio_triggered_buffer_postenab le’ undeclared here (not in a
> function); did you mean ‘iio_triggered_buffer_cleanup’?   .postenable
> = iio_triggered_buffer_postenable,
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 iio_triggered_buffer_cleanup /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/adc/ti-ads1015.c:798:16:
> error: ‘iio_triggered_buffer_predisab le’ undeclared here (not in a
> function); did you mean ‘iio_triggered_buffer_cleanup’?   .predisable
> = iio_triggered_buffer_predisable,
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                 iio_triggered_buffer_cleanup make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:279:
> /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/adc/ti-ads1015.o] Er ror
> 1 make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:496:
> /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build/adc] Error 2 make: ***
> [Makefile:1808: /var/lib/dkms/coral-enviro-drivers/1.5/build] Error 2
> make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.11+'
```

The Coral Enviro Sensor displays the temperature and the pressure, but displays NaN for luminance and relative humidity, which I think corresponds to the errors I am seeing in the build process.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm facing same problem. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Short answer to your question, @christian-arias, 'no'. I haven't gotten the relative humidity and light sensors working on the board yet. Coral support sent me instructions to recompile the kernel after changing the IIO module settings, but when I recompiled the kernel, I had the same problem.  I have yet to try another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The package is using DKMS to install kernel modules. The Pi kernel does not have all of the IIO modules needed, most notably IIO_TRIGGER. Here are the IIO modules that we install on Coral devices: https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx-debian/+/refs/heads/master/debian/defconfig#148

Detailed general instructions to build the kernel for RPI are given at : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/configuring.md

Write CONFIG_IIO=y and CONFIG_IIO_TRIGGER=y, then recompile the kernel and load it to your RPI zero and then try to install the Enviro Sensor drivers again. If you skip this, you probably will have everything else except the ADC work (since it's the only one with the buffered trigger call).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like about year ago ther was a change in the kernell code that moves this two functions from every driver to inside the core, so probably deleting this two lines is good idea. https://lore.kernel.org/linux-iio/20200522104632.517470-1-alexandru.ardelean@analog.com/

Answer (score -1):

I commented out the two lines. I'm nearly positive that will break something but it did compiled everything else.